# Different behavior seen accessing value in stored variable vs function call that returns the variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

Apologies for what must be a total newbie question.  I'm starting to play with Backbone talking to an existing Rails app.  I'm using the Console in Chrome to test out some JS functions, and I'm seeing behavior that I cannot understand.

I've defined a JS function called `apiGet` which just wraps a jQuery AJAX call with some custom stuff jammed into the HTTP request header.

When I call `apiGet` and store the result in a variable, I can then call `.responseText` on that variable and see the contents of that field.

However, if I just try to call `.responseText` on the `apiGet(...)` call, i.e. `apiGet(...).responseText` the result displayed is `undefined`.  This makes no sense to me :-)

I'm missing something obvious -- can someone clue me in?

Here's what the console looks like:

```
> var url = 'http://localhost:3002/api/exercises/11';
  undefined
> result = apiGet(url);
  Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
> result.responseText
  "{"id":1,"number":2,"version":1,"markup":null,"html":null,"background":null}"
> apiGet(url).responseText
  undefined
```

Comment: You need to post the source of `apiGet`, is it returning an object with a `responseText` attribute?

Comment: Yeah, we need `apiGet`. sure sounds like it's asynchronous. Perhaps it returns an object that is updated when the response get's back. Thus, your `result = apiGet(url)` is being updated in the console, but in your `apiGet(url).responseText`, `responseText` does not exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your function `apiGet` returns an xhr (request object). This will execute asynchronously, so that `responseText` isn't available until the response comes back from the server. When you call the property directly on the return, it happens so fast that the server hasn't responded yet, but when you use the console manually, by the time you type out `result.responseText` and press enter, the result is already in.

Just a guess of course, since I haven't seen the contents of `getApi`.

Comment: Yep, that is it! Too many years doing synchronous dev.  I recall that the last time that I started up on a JS project I was bitten by the same thing.  Maybe next time I'll have learned my lesson. Put a `console.log` statement in the `success` property in the Ajax call, and all is well.